# Is receipt verification required for free newsstand subscriptions?

Tags: ios, push-notification, newsstand-kit

My newsstand app only offers one subscription and it is free. I know newsstand apps will be rejected if they do not use iTunes Connect subscriptions.

Will apple care that I never validate the receipt. The only thing I use the receipt for is to determine if they have subscribed or not and if they have then I register for push notifications.

Also, it doesn't seem like the concept of an "issue" as in the issue information that is posted to iTunes Connect is strictly necessary....

Answer (score 1):

@Revanth I think 1 issue is necessary in 3 months, i.e ,4 issues in a year. but as you saying issue is not mandatory can you please provide any link in favour of your answer related to that issue part, i am also looking for this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Receipt validation is not mandatory for a Newsstand app approval.

The issues part is also not mandatory unless you provide the default cover art for your app.